# Prevent PHP file from downloading

Tags: php

I just found out that everyone can download my php files by pressing the <kbd>alt</kbd> key and left-clicking.

However, every other website prevents visitors from downloding their source file by replacing the download with a static html file.

I don't know how to hide my source files. Can anyone help? Did I somehow mess up my server settings?

Comment: People cannot download your PHP source unless your server is not set up right and the raw source is served anyway because the file is not being handled by PHP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're not downloading your PHP files, they just download the static HTML produced by your PHP script. The ability to download the PHP **source** is down to the server configuration.

Answer (score 3):

You are saying that if you click on the `file.php` normal way it runs as expected and you see **output** of that PHP script but if you click with ALT then you can download **source** of that file? I really doubt so. All you can download is probably **output** of your script.

Answer (score 2):

They are no downloading the actual php code that you have. They only get your output just like your browser does. you can do the same thing if you press CTRL + S on the page.

So you don't have to worry about that as long as your php code id compiled.

Answer (score 2):

PHP is *interpreted* and spits out some output (using `echo`s and `print` statements) that is sent to the browser AS plain HTML. They CANNOT "download your PHP". Unless you're offering the source code files `.phps` (conventionally).